# How to download full data to a byte array

Tags: android, download

I want to download a zip file via a url. And I want to encrypt that without writing to the sd card. How to get full byte data from the url? 
Thanks in advance

```
protected String doInBackground(String... url) {
        int count;
        try {
            URL url1 = new URL(url[0]);
            URLConnection conexion = url1.openConnection();
            conexion.connect();
            // this will be useful so that you can show a tipical 0-100%
            // progress bar
            int lenghtOfFile = conexion.getContentLength();

            // download the file
            InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url1.openStream());
            OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(
                    "/sdcard/downloaded.zip");

            byte data[] = new byte[1024];
            long total = 0;

            while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {

                total += count;
                // publishing the progress....
                publishProgress((int) (total * 100 / lenghtOfFile));
                output.write(data, 0, count);
            }

            output.flush();
            output.close();
            input.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: I hope u understand that there is a limited memory available on your phone

Comment: @the100rabh: Ya. I know that.. But my problem is to encrypt the data before writing to the sd card..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `ByteArrayOutputStream()` and after downloading call `toByteArray()` function.